# Terraform: associate an aws_iam_role_policy to an aws_iam_role

Tags: amazon-iam, terraform

I'm attempting to attach an *aws_iam_role_policy* to an *aws_iam_role* using Terraform variables: `${aws_iam_role.AutoTagMasterRole.id}`

I'm using the TF docs found at: [iam_role_policy.html](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy.html)

**Terraform error message:**

> aws_iam_role_policy.AutoTagMasterPolicy: Resource
>   'aws_iam_role.AutoTagMasterRole' not found for variable
>   'aws_iam_role.AutoTagMasterRole.arn'

**Here's my Terraform configuration:**

```
  resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "AutoTagMasterPolicy" {
    name  = "AutoTagMasterPolicy"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.AutoTagMasterRole.id}"


    policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:GetBucketTagging",
          "s3:PutBucketTagging",
          "ec2:CreateTags",
          "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
          "autoscaling:CreateOrUpdateTags",
          "rds:AddTagsToResource",
          "elasticmapreduce:AddTags",
          "datapipeline:AddTags"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
  }



  resource "aws_iam_role" "AutoTagMasterRole" {
    name = "AutoTagMasterRole"
    path = "/gorillastack/autotag/master/"

    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": { "${aws_iam_role.AutoTagExecutionRole.arn}" }
        },
        "Action": [
          "sts:AssumeRole"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
  }
```

Can someone tell me what it is I've done incorrectly?

**UPDATE**  I've been told this relates to my attempt at porting the cloudformation function to it's equivalent in terraform.

This is what cloudformation lists:

```
   "Principal": {
            "AWS" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AutoTagExecutionRole", "Arn" ] }
          },
```

I am trying to find the equivalent in terraform.  This is what I used, but it's throwing the error.

```
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": { "${aws_iam_role.AutoTagExecutionRole.arn}" }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `Principal` is wrong in aws_iam_role

Here is the sample for you.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

So your codes should be changed to

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "AutoTagMasterRole" {
  name = "AutoTagMasterRole"
  path = "/gorillastack/autotag/master/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
          "sts:AssumeRole"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}
```

Refer: [terraform aws_iam_role](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html)

Comment: The terraform $terraform var that was listed for principal was my attempt at converting cloudformation's function:   "Principal": {
                "AWS" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AutoTagExecutionRole", "Arn" ] }
              },             That's what I'm trying to port over to terraform.  Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure that Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com" is the equivelant

Comment: BMW, thank you, you were correct, it was the Principal.  My syntax was incorrect and I had an extra set of {}. The invalid syntax caused failure in writing that resource to the tf.state file which triggered those errors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After troubleshooting realized I had incorrect syntax:

```
"Principal": {
      "AWS": { "${aws_iam_role.AutoTagExecutionRole.arn}" }
    },
```

Should be:

```
"Principal": {
      "AWS": "${aws_iam_role.AutoTagExecutionRole.arn}"
    },
```

The incorrect syntax (although not accurately reported by Terraform) caused the aws_iam_role to fail writing to the tf.state file which caused the error message reporting the failure to find the resources.